# jQuery Chosen doesn't update select options while working with knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-chosen

I am trying to make [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) work at the same time.

The problem is "jQuery Chosen" refuses to update options list even though I've created custom binding for it.

Here is the example - http://jsfiddle.net/5fGAf/

I have two changeable selects - "Country" and "Method". "Method" options list depends on country selected. When I select the country for the first time - everything works perfect. But when I want to change the country - "Method" options list remains the same, even though corresponding knockout computed value is updated.

If I manually run  `$(".chosen-select").trigger('chosen:updated')` in the browser console - options list updates.

Custom binding code:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
  init: function(element) {             
    $(element).chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
  },
  update: function(element) {
    $(".chosen-select").trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have two problems:

- in your fiddle there is no `.chosen-select` so your `update` function does not find the `select` but anyway you should use `$(element)` to access the currently bound element
- in [KO 3.0 bindings are fired independently](http://knockoutjs.com/upgrade-notes/v3.0.0.html#bindings-are-now-refreshed-independently). Because your `chosen` binding is not connected to the your observable array your `update` won't fire when you change that array.

You can solve this "update" problem with explicitly declaring a dependency on the `options` binding in your custom binding but a better solution would be to delegate to it:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function(element)  {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element);
        $(element).chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
        $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
};
```

And use it where you would normally use the `options` binding:

```
<select id="option1" class="form-control" 
    data-bind="chosen: payoutOptions, 
               optionsText: 'optionText', 
               optionsValue: 'optionValue', 
               value: activePayoutOption"></select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxMqV/).

Comment: Faced an issue while using this solution - if observable, responsible for selected chosen option is reseted (`observableVariable(null)`) - chosen doesn't update properly. Here is the example - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxMqV/). Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is twofold: the the one hand since KO 3.0 your custom update does not triggered when the your selected observable changes and the other hand the chosen plugin does not handle automatically if something change the selection value. So you need to manually subscribe on the `value` binding and trigger the `chosen:update` when the underlaying observable changes: here is a sample using the updated binding handler: http://jsfiddle.net/SWEt2/

Comment: Excellent answer nemesv - hopefully if anyone else comes across this they upvote as it is a better solution than the higher rated Google result.

Comment: @nemesv One problem with the fiddle appears to be that if you use optionsCaption it clears the value of the dropdown without having the options binding.  http://jsfiddle.net/VxMqV/6/  Any thoughts?

Comment: in my case `chosen:updated` event triggered when value changes, does not update the selected option. any thoughts?

Comment: @nemesv You're a man.. You solved my headache.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen =
{
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        $(element).chosen(valueAccessor());

        // trigger chosen:updated event when the bound value or options changes

        $.each('value|selectedOptions|options'.split("|"), function (i, e) {
            var bv = allBindings.get(e);
            if (ko.isObservable(bv))
                bv.subscribe(function () { $(element).trigger('chosen:updated'); });
        });
    },
    update: function (element) {
        $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
};
```

You'd use it like so:

```
<select data-bind="
    options: payoutOptions, 
    optionsText: 'optionText', 
    optionsValue: 'optionValue',
    value: activePayoutOption,
    chosen: { disable_search_threshold: 10, width:'100%' }">
</select>
```

Note that

1. The *chosen* binding is option is added...rather than changing the way the given binding works
2. Chosen options (`{ width:'100%',... }`) are not hardwired in the handler

Answer (score 2):

I used a method that is also compatible with all my existing bindings, so I didn't need to go though a ton of html files removing the `options` binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        $(element).chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 10});
        var valueObservable = allBindings.get('value');
        var optionsObservable = allBindings.get('options');

        var updateList = function() {
            $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
        }

        if (valueObservable && typeof(valueObservable.subscribe) == 'function') {
            valueObservable.subscribe(updateList);
        }

        if (optionsObservable && typeof(optionsObservable.subscribe) == 'function') {
            optionsObservable.subscribe(updateList);
        }

        $(element).chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 7, width:'100%' });
    }
};
```