# Knockout with Chosen doesn't set the initial selected options

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-chosen

I'm having trouble setting the initially selected options with [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and Knockout 3.3.0.

I've implemented the custom Chosen binding from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022261/jquery-chosen-doesnt-update-select-options-while-working-with-knockout-js), which works great for selecting elements:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element);
        $(element).chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 10 });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
        $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
};
```

The problem is, if I set an initial value, it won't show it as selected:

```
<select multiple class="chosen-select" data-bind="chosen: options,
                                        optionsText: 'Label',
                                        optionsValue: 'Id',
                                        selectedOptions: selected">
</select>
```

If I use the regular options binding, it works correctly:

```
<select multiple data-bind="options: options,
                                        optionsText: 'Label',
                                        optionsValue: 'Id',
                                        selectedOptions: selected">
</select>
```

I've implemented both as a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ubmpxay/1/). If you change the `self.selected` observableArray(), and then run, you can see it reflected in the second `<select>`, but nothing shows in the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to also angument the `selectedOptions` binding to work correctly with the `chosen` if the `select` is in multiple selection mode.

The problem is that when your `selected` observable array changes the `selectedOptions` correctly sets the selected options in the DOM but does not trigger the `'chosen:updated'` event so the `chosen` multiselect is not updated.

One solution would be to create a new `chosenSelectedOptions` which delegates to the original handler and triggers the event in the `update`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosenSelectedOptions = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions.init(element, valueAccessor);
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
                $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
            }
        };
```

And use that in your binding:

```
<select multiple class="chosen-select" data-bind="chosen: options,
                                            optionsText: 'Label',
                                            optionsValue: 'Id',
                                            chosenSelectedOptions: selected"></select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g53tdph7/).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to to evaluate the chosen thing after the binding has happened because chosen won't init properly without the `<options>` being in the DOM.

This is slightly ugly to use setTimeout but it works because it will delay that re-init until after the binding is complete.

EDIT:
Using subscriptions to deal with changes to selected options. I find this more self-contained than the accepted answer.

** FIDDLE: **

https://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/xp1b7cff/

**JS:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor);
        var el = $(element);
        el.chosen();
        var selectedOptions = allBindings.get('selectedOptions');
        if (ko.isObservable(selectedOptions)) {
            selectedOptions.subscribe(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    el.trigger('chosen:updated');
                }, 10);
            }, null, 'change');
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    }
};

    function viewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.options = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1, Label: 'Administrator' }, { Id: 2, Label: 'Moderator' }]);

        self.selected = ko.observableArray([2]);

    }
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: Your solution is not working correctly! It only works when the page initially loaded. If you later the change the selection in the non chosen select (right) the changes are not reflected in the chosen select (left). So if the `selected` observable changes then it does not correctly update the chosen select (left)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your edit. I'm going to give it a try this weekend and see if it works. I like that it's entirely self contained, like you mentioned.